# Some pixels on the screen in a big rectangular shape are darker than the rest

Tags: 16.04, screen

Fairly new to ubuntu here (16.04)~ installed it two-three days ago and noticed those rectangles yesterday, although it was in a different location and shape then.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this an old CRT display, or plasma, or something else? It looks like screen burn-in.

Comment: @heynnema I've no idea what type of display it is but it's VERY old, at least 5 years old laptop. However, I didn't have this issue until I installed Ubuntu, so I was thinking more of a software bug? unless ubuntu somehow caused the screen burn-in?

Comment: Tell me the make/model #.

Comment: fujitsu lifebook ah531

Comment: Check if your BIOS is 1.30. If not, go to http://support.fujitsupc.com/CS/Portal/supportsearch.do?srch=DOWNLOADS&Series=A%20Series&Model=AH531&ProductType=Notebook%20PC and download/install it. Go to memtest86.org, download the free memory diagnostic and run it. Report back.

Comment: How do i check my "BIOS"? what's that even :/ I'll try the other ones and report back, probably tomorrow though, its 3AM here

Comment: To check your BIOS, at power on, watch the splash screen, and it'll tell you what key to press to enter the BIOS (low level computer instructions), like DEL, or ESC, or F12. Something like that. Once there, find the version number.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  And it appeared to be my 'Screenshot' tool which I use quite a bit.  I simply opened and closed the tool and the black rectangle went away